# embed facebook group feed

Tags: facebook, api, feed, facebook-group

I am trying to embed the feed of a face book group in a webpage.
Following the API reference I would expect to get this when requesting the 'feed'

I tried it on the Graph API explorer, but the feed is empty?
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=40147298084%3Ffields%3Dfeed

Can anyone guide me how to get the feed from a facebook group, btw this is an open group.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see the feed are you sure you are using a valid access token?

Comment: I can see the feed.have you logged in and given permissions to the tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a permissions issue. Make sure you're passing a valid `access_token` and that the token is auth'd to see the content you're trying to view.

It sometimes trips people up, but it's important to remember that even if a piece of content is totally public, there are situations where you'll need a token to view it.